# audio buffer with librosa

Tags: audio, buffer, librosa

In the following code I created a buffer which holds 10 frames of an audio file in each loop iteration.

```
import collections
import librosa
import wave
my_buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=10)
f = wave.open('Desktop/0963.wav',"rb")
num_frames = f.getnframes()
for frame in range(num_frames):
   my_buffer.append(f.readframes(frame))
```

Out of the buffer, I need to get a numpy array representing audio amplitude of each sample point with librosa. Any idea?

Comment: Added answer using `scipy.io.wavfile`. Do check out and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [scipy.io.wavfile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) , it will directly read a wave file and load data to an numpy array. Which you can then slice as per your requirements.

`scipy.io.wavfile` reads a WAV file and returns the sample rate (in samples/sec) and data from the WAV file

```
>>> type(f)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> f
(44100, array([-36,  57, 156, ...,  66,  64,  77], dtype=int16))
>>>
```

**Source Code**

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import numpy as np
f = read('your_audio.wav')
n = np.array(f[1],dtype=float)
for i in xrange(0,len(n),10):
    my_buffer = n[i:i+10]
```

my_buffer contents:

```
>>> 
[ -36.   57.  156.  198.  191.  126.   70.   42.   43.   62.]
[  69.   71.   83.  117.  159.  177.  151.   89.   14.  -27.]
[ -33.   -4.   21.   38.   42.   66.   94.  134.  144.  142.]
[ 118.  115.  111.  132.  122.  123.  103.  119.  125.  134.]
.....
.....
```

Here we have `my_buffer` with 10 frames per iteration that you can feed into next block.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, scipy.io.wavfile is a good module for reading in and handling audio. If you want to stick with librosa, you can use this to do the same:

```
import librosa

filepath = 'Desktop/0963.wav'
samplerate = 44100

audio, samplerate = librosa.load(filepath, sr=samplerate)
audio.shape
```

What I like about librosa.load is that you can specify any sample rate to downsample an audio file to. Hope this helps.